# Restart Ruby without restarting the server

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, arch-linux

I need to reload some files for ruby on my server, how do i restart ruby as it isnt a daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something isn't running continually, then when it next starts it will read the new files.  My crystal ball suggests you're actually referring to a Passenger instance; that *is* a daemon, but it's one that is "slaved" to Apache.  If you restart Apache, that should do the trick, however Rails (and Passenger) is supposed to have some sort of auto-reloading shenanigan going on, but I guess that isn't working (or you're missing something).

Comment: I had to edit one of the ruby "source" files, essentially i need to kill all instances of ruby so that one the files can be reloaded in RAM, i might just reboot the server probabbly the fastest solution

Comment: `*facepalm*`...

Answer (score 2):

Restart Rails application under Passenger:

touch /path/to/your/app/tmp/restart.txt

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html#restart-txt